# Can virtual machine (hyper-v) control its mouse programatically using pyautogui while I use my mouse freely in the host OS?

Tags: python, virtual-machine, hyper-v, pyautogui

So what I want to do is to write a python script using pyautogui in a virtual machine to do some kind of automation so that it won't use my real mouse in the host OS.

Can I achieve this?

I'm asking this because I can't use a virtual machine right now so it would be great if someone knew the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this with pyautogui, but you need a connected user on the virtual machine. If you still want to use the mouse on the host system you must executed the code on the virtual machine.

I see that you want to make some automation. Maybe you should take a look at solutions for mouse record automations.

You might like this https://automatetheboringstuff.com/chapter18/ - This is a great tutorial to automate mouse and keyboard actions with python and pyautogui.